# What are the brightest bulbs for projector headlamps?

Tags: chevrolet, headlight, silverado

I bought some projector headlights with Hi 55 watt bulbs in both the high and low beam modes. The low beam, which is the projector lens, isn't that bright.

**What other bulbs would be recommended for a brighter light with the projector lens without spending a lot of money?**

Has anyone else run across this issue before when replacing the low beam?

Comment: What year is your Silverado? What *exact bulb* (manufacturer and model) of bulb you purchased?